# Styling issue in IE - huge space displaying

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, styling

Hey guys so I have the follow:

http://jsfiddle.net/z3Hr2/

This is my nav that I use to access in JQuery, tables...here is a photo:

[image]

Now when I click one of the links a table pops up, like this:

[image]

The problem is that in IE there is a huge gap in between the top to the bottom, even though they are `display:none` ( the tables that are opened when clicking a nav link).

Here is what I mean in IE:

[image]

Here is the table containers layout:

```
<div class="csvemployeestools">
   <div class="MemberopenstatusViewer">
      <div class="OpenstatusViewertable">
          table that is opened depending on which link clicked in nav....
      </div>
   <div>
    .....


</div> <!-- after all tables are defined, this closes it out.
```

CSS:

```
.csvemployeestools{

    margin-top: 2%;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.MemberopenstatusViewer{
    display:block;
    /*float:left;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: .7em;
    width:100%;
    /*overflow-x: scroll;*/

}
.OpenstatusViewertable {
    width:100%; 
    max-height: 300px;
overflow-y: scroll;
margin-bottom: 3%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but you should be using div IDs for layout not classes.

This is much better:

```
(class = . )(id = #)
```

But I'm not sure how this relates to this question.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out though :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I figured it out....I just removed the divs around the tables:

```
<div class="MemberopenstatusViewer">
      <div class="OpenstatusViewertable">

      </div>
   <div>
```

Thanks though!